# Blackfire profiling not working

Tags: php, blackfire

So I followed [these instructions](https://blackfire.io/docs/up-and-running/installation#installation-instructions) for my vagrant box and everything seemed to go fine, I mean its running. It has been configured with its server id and server token.

I then installed the PHP Probe, as per the instructions on the same page and restarted apache2 when it was done. I then did `composer require 
blackfire/php-sdk` and finally in my code I did:

```
$probe = $blackfire->createProbe();

// some PHP code you want to profile

$blackfire->endProbe($probe);
dd('End here.'); // Laravels die and dump function.
```

So as far as I know I did everything right. Then, in my console I did:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$ php artisan fetch_eve_online_region_type_history_information


  [Blackfire\Exception\ApiException]                                                                                                      
  401:  while calling GET https://blackfire.io/api/v1/collab-tokens [context: NULL] [headers: array (                                     
    0 => 'Authorization: Basic xxxxxx=',                                                                                                       
    1 => 'X-Blackfire-User-Agent: Blackfire PHP SDK/1.0',                                                                                 
  )]

 // where xxxx is some kind of authentication token that looks different from what I gave as my server id and token.
```

uh .... Ok so the docs state if something goes wrong to check the logs:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$ cat /var/log/blackfire/agent.log
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$
```

Theres nothing in the logs....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've seen the issue you created on GitHub for this, and it was suggested to contact them directly. If there is a generic issue or gotcha here, could you please share what you have done to resolve your issue? That would help others with the same problem (like me). Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Not a real solution, but rather a workaround until we hear more about how to actually solve it.

I have added the client credentials manually directly in the code and it solved the issue for me:

```
    $config = new \Blackfire\ClientConfiguration();
    $config->setClientId('...your _client_ id...');
    $config->setClientToken('...your _client_ token...');

    $blackfire = new \Blackfire\Client($config);
```

The string that I saw in the error was `Authorization: Basic Og==` and `Og==` is just a base64-encoded string `:`, which hints that username/password (or id/token in this case?) automatic lookup failed and authorization is impossible. That's why providing the details manually works around it.

Comment: Thanks, I solved by defining environment variables for `BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID` and `BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN` in my docker PHP container

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but maybe someone will need it in the future.
Adding the HOME environment variable to apache's vhost file so blackfire finds ~/.blackfire.ini solves it.

```
<VirtualHost hostname:80>
    ...
    SetEnv HOME /Users/me #i'm running macOS, on linux would be /home/me
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you have many VirtualHosts on your machine, you can also add it to your main APACHE config, which will fix all of them in one go.

Answer (score 0):

consider that your probe configuration is correct (server_id & server_tokens) and you can profile from the browser , for using PHP SDK (phpunit integration with blackfire) you have to configure the client side :

- `apt-get install blackfire-agent`
- `blackfire config` you will prompt for **BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID** and **BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN** .

  you can also login to this [api/v1/collab-tokens](https://blackfire.io/api/v1/collab-tokens) to test your client credentials username=>**BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID** , password=>**BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN**

the config file location for the client : `/root/.blackfire.ini`